# in #MVC3 is there a way to add the HTML5 placeholder attribute using a DataAnnotations attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3

given this is my model

```
public class ValidationModel
{
    #region Properties

    [Display(Prompt = "type a PostCode here")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

}
```

and this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostCode)

}
```

is there a way to make it render

```
<input data-val="true" id="PostCode" name="PostCode" placeholder="type a PostCode here" type="text" value="" />
```

I could not make it work even if from the documentation http://bit.ly/jVpM8X I can clearly see Display Prompt should do the job

Comment: Please visit our http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap site to request this. Let me know if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, but it looks like watermarking has made it into the metadata code (there is a clear standard way to define a string that goes with a property) but not the view code as there is not yet a universally supported way to handle watermarks on the client side.

If adding the attributes manually won't work, the best option is probably to create a new HTML helper Html5TextBoxFor and use that instead of the standard TextBoxFor.

Within that helper, you can get the prompt text with ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression and then call TextBoxFor using a custom html attributes object generated from the metadata.

Answer (score 15):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostCode, 
    new { placeholder = "type a postcode ..." } )
```

Comment: yep, I saw that, but I want to use the the DataAnnotaion attributes (Display Prompt) on the model, I do not want to add the placeholder attribute from the view

Answer (score 9):

I needed this exact functionality, but I didn't want to go around and change all my `EditorFor`'s to be something different (I have a **lot** of pages :)).

To achieve this, I simply created a `EditorTemplate` for `String` (you can do this for other types should you need it).

Based on my model properties, which I use `DisplayName`, like so:

```
[DisplayName("Client Name")]
public string ClientName { get; set; }
```

The template was simply:

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName })
```

And then my calling code stayed exactly the same:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Additionally, you can have this work for non-HTML5 browsers with that **exact** code. All I did was add a script reference to [**this great jQuery placeholder plugin**](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) and all my placeholders even work in IE6(!!!!).

Answer (score 1):

Any html attribute in razor view can be added to the **HTML helper** by assigning property's value in `@html.control` using the `new {}` keyword then defining the attribute by starting with `@` symbol if you are using a reserved keyword in razor that represents html attribute like `class` you need to add `@` before that word, the same way Razor engine treats HTML DOM elements for example:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Name" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own HtmlHelper extension method to do it as described in this article:
http://mvcdiary.com/2012/09/28/create-a-custom-htmlhelper-textboxfor-to-display-label-text-as-placeholder-integrated-with-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Although you may not ever actually do this, as a proof of concept you could do this:

Model:

```
[Required, Display(Description = "Type your note here...")]
public string Note { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Note, new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata
    .Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == "Note")?.Description })
```